# What subquery do I need to calculate this report?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: tickets and comments. I need to run a report that shows me which ticket is "neglected" meaning that there has not been a comment in X amount of time.

If I was to do this in PHP, I would load ticket, then do a separate query for each one, see what the most recent timestamp was (max(comment_ts)), and keep the values of the "old tickets" in an array, then display them from there. But, it seems I should be able to do this as a single query via MySQL and it would be much faster, so I am trying to create a view for this.

Assume this is the basic table structure:

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 07/18/14 17:29:39
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`tickets`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tickets` (
  `ticket_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `ticket_description` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`comments`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`comments` (
  `comments_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `comments_comment` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `comments_timestamp` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comments_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `comments_bug`
    FOREIGN KEY (`comments_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`tickets` (`ticket_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: From the posted table definitions it looks like you will only ever have one row in `comments` for each row in `tickets`.  True?

Comment: Thanks Verace. Tried to upvote you, but I don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this far (DDL and DML below)

```
SELECT ticket_id, c_max_date FROM
( 
  SELECT ticket_id, MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(comment.comments_timestamp)) AS c_max_date
  FROM comment
  WHERE comment.comments_timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
  GROUP BY ticket_id
) AS mytab;

+-----------+---------------------+
| ticket_id | c_max_date          |
+-----------+---------------------+
|         3 | 2004-07-09 15:15:30 |
|         4 | 2006-06-30 15:15:30 |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

These two comments are indeed the ticket number of tickets whose comments haven't been updated in 2 years (arbitrary choice). The dates are the dates of the last update to the ticket comments.

Can you (anyone) put the finishing touch to this and join mytab to tickets? My brain is fried!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticket
(
  ticket_id INT NOT NULL,
  ticket_description TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ticket_id)
);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comment 
(
  comment_id INT NOT NULL,
  ticket_id INT NOT NULL,
  comments_comment VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  comments_timestamp INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (comment_id),
  INDEX ticket_index (ticket_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (ticket_id) REFERENCES ticket (ticket_id)
);


INSERT INTO ticket VALUES(1, 'ticket 1');
INSERT INTO ticket VALUES(2, 'ticket 2');
INSERT INTO ticket VALUES(3, 'ticket 3');
INSERT INTO ticket VALUES(4, 'ticket 4');
INSERT INTO ticket VALUES(5, 'ticket 5');

INSERT INTO comment VALUES(1, 1, 'comment 1 on ticket 1', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-11-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(2, 1, 'comment 2 on ticket 1', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-13 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(3, 1, 'comment 3 on ticket 1', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-06-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(4, 1, 'comment 4 on ticket 1', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-09 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(5, 2, 'comment 1 on ticket 2', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-11-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(6, 2, 'comment 2 on ticket 2', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-13 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(7, 2, 'comment 3 on ticket 2', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(8, 2, 'comment 4 on ticket 2', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-09 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(9, 3, 'comment 1 on ticket 3', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2003-11-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(10, 3, 'comment 2 on ticket 3', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2002-02-13 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(11, 3, 'comment 3 on ticket 3', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2004-06-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(12, 3, 'comment 4 on ticket 3', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2004-07-09 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(13, 4, 'comment 1 on ticket 4', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2003-11-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(14, 4, 'comment 2 on ticket 4', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2004-02-13 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(15, 4, 'comment 3 on ticket 4', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2006-06-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(16, 4, 'comment 4 on ticket 4', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2004-07-09 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(17, 5, 'comment 1 on ticket 1', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-11-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(18, 5, 'comment 2 on ticket 2', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-13 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(19, 5, 'comment 3 on ticket 3', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-06-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(20, 5, 'comment 4 on ticket 4', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-09 15:15:30'));
```

Comment: Did you manage to figure this one out? It's still bugging me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this again, and I figured out how to get the answer, but it's a horrible hack (DDL and DML below - just changed values from my last answer). The reason that I changed some values was that on running my queries with my orignal data, there are 2 results returned for ticket 3 by the second query which is incorrect. This was because there was a match between another commend date in ticket 3 which matched a comment date in ticket 4.

So, in addition to being an appalling hack (**temporary table!**), should you choose to use what I have posted, you'll have to be absolutely certain that there can never be a match between dates (to the second) if you choose to use Unix timestamps. You could reduce this risk by using the NOW(3) function (millisecond) or even the MICROSECOND function (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_microsecond)) to add precision.

I know that there's a more elegant (one-pass query) solution, but I just can't see it (any takers?). This solution will not (IMHO) scale well and breaches one of the fundamental rules of database programming - no DDL on the live system.

First, I created a temporary table (temp_table) like this (extra fields included for human readability).

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table AS 
(
  SELECT * FROM
  ( 
    SELECT ticket_id, MAX(c.comments_timestamp) AS c_max_date, MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(c.comments_timestamp))
    FROM comment c
    WHERE c.comments_timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
    GROUP BY ticket_id
  ) AS mytab
);

mysql> select * from temp_table;
+-----------+------------+------------------------------------------+
| ticket_id | c_max_date | MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(c.comments_timestamp)) |
+-----------+------------+------------------------------------------+
|         3 | 1089382530 | 2004-07-09 15:15:30                      |
|         4 | 1151669730 | 2006-06-30 13:15:30                      |
+-----------+------------+------------------------------------------+
```

And then I issued the following query (again fields added for human readability).

```
SELECT t2.ticket_id, t.ticket_description, t2.c_max_date, 
FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.c_max_date), c.comment_id, c.comments_comment,
FROM_UNIXTIME(c.comments_timestamp) AS d_c_max_date
FROM ticket t, temp_table t2, comment c
WHERE t.ticket_id = t2.ticket_id
AND t2.c_max_date = c.comments_timestamp;

+-----------+--------------------+------------+------------------------------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
| ticket_id | ticket_description | c_max_date | FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.c_max_date) | comment_id | comments_comment      | d_c_max_date        |
+-----------+--------------------+------------+------------------------------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|         3 | ticket 3           | 1089382530 | 2004-07-09 15:15:30          |         12 | comment 4 on ticket 3 | 2004-07-09 15:15:30 |
|         4 | ticket 4           | 1151669730 | 2006-06-30 13:15:30          |         15 | comment 3 on ticket 4 | 2006-06-30 13:15:30 |
+-----------+--------------------+------------+------------------------------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

======== DDL and DML for the tables ===========

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticket
(
  ticket_id INT NOT NULL,
  ticket_description TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ticket_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comment 
(
  comment_id INT NOT NULL,
  ticket_id INT NOT NULL,
  comments_comment VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  comments_timestamp INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (comment_id),
  INDEX ticket_index (ticket_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (ticket_id) REFERENCES ticket (ticket_id)
);

INSERT INTO ticket VALUES(1, 'ticket 1');
INSERT INTO ticket VALUES(2, 'ticket 2');
INSERT INTO ticket VALUES(3, 'ticket 3');
INSERT INTO ticket VALUES(4, 'ticket 4');
INSERT INTO ticket VALUES(5, 'ticket 5');


INSERT INTO comment VALUES(1, 1, 'comment 1 on ticket 1', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-11-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(2, 1, 'comment 2 on ticket 1', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-13 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(3, 1, 'comment 3 on ticket 1', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-06-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(4, 1, 'comment 4 on ticket 1', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-09 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(5, 2, 'comment 1 on ticket 2', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-11-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(6, 2, 'comment 2 on ticket 2', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-13 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(7, 2, 'comment 3 on ticket 2', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(8, 2, 'comment 4 on ticket 2', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-09 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(9, 3, 'comment 1 on ticket 3', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2003-11-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(10, 3, 'comment 2 on ticket 3', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2002-02-13 15:16:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(11, 3, 'comment 3 on ticket 3', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2004-06-30 15:17:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(12, 3, 'comment 4 on ticket 3', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2004-07-09 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(13, 4, 'comment 1 on ticket 4', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2003-11-30 15:18:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(14, 4, 'comment 2 on ticket 4', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2004-02-13 14:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(15, 4, 'comment 3 on ticket 4', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2006-06-30 13:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(16, 4, 'comment 4 on ticket 4', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2004-07-09 12:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(17, 5, 'comment 1 on ticket 1', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-11-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(18, 5, 'comment 2 on ticket 2', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-13 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(19, 5, 'comment 3 on ticket 3', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-06-30 15:15:30'));
INSERT INTO comment VALUES(20, 5, 'comment 4 on ticket 4', UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-09 15:15:30'));
```